# Pandas groupby max - multiple columns

Tags: pandas, max

after grouping to max value in pandas, how to display the matching row result entirely along max() value

```
df = data.loc[:,['no','std_date','result_date','result']]
result = df.groupby(['no','std_date'])[['result_date','result']].max()
```

I display the result on each 'std_date' and send the result.
but, now the maximum value of each column of 'result_date' and 'result'.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udTeo.png)

My data:

```
    no  std_date    result_date result
0   s1  2012-12-24  2012-07-03  601.19
1   s2  2011-11-23  2011-05-16  1.96
2   s2  2011-11-23  2011-11-10  15.2
3   s3  2016-08-10  2016-04-23  14.05
4   s5  2013-11-12  2013-05-31  34.73
5   s5  2013-11-12  2013-07-22  12
6   s5  2017-11-14  2014-05-09  0.59
7   s5  2017-11-14  2016-09-07  0.8
8   s5  2017-11-14  2017-06-20  1.54
9   s6  2012-06-01  2012-05-14  1.08
10  s7  2018-11-19  2018-04-10  25.74
11  s7  2018-11-19  2018-10-16  12.49
12  s8  2013-12-24  2013-10-17  26.48
13  s8  2016-01-20  2013-12-31  1.36
14  s8  2016-01-20  2014-08-27  0.9
15  s8  2016-01-20  2015-06-29  3.72
```

I want:

```
                   result_date  result
no  std_date        
s1  2012-12-24  2012-11-28  601.19
s2  2011-11-23  2011-11-10  15.2
s3  2016-08-10  2016-04-23  14.05
s5  2013-11-12  2013-07-22  12
s5  2017-11-14  2017-06-20  1.54
s6  2012-06-01  2012-05-14  1.08
s7  2018-11-19  2018-10-16  12.49
s8  2013-12-24  2013-10-17  26.48
s8  2016-01-20  2015-06-29  3.72
```

Comment: I want to output the result value of max 'result_date' of each 'std_date'.So, "s5 2013-11-12 | 2013-05-31 (34.73) <2013-07-22 (12)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave the result off and then merge it back to the DataFrame

```py
result = df.groupby(['no','std_date'])[['result_date']]\
    .max()\
    .reset_index()\
    .merge(df,on=['no','std_date','result_date'])
```

**Output:**

```
   no  std_date result_date  result
0  s1  12-12-24    12-07-03  601.19
1  s2  11-11-23    11-11-10   15.20
2  s3  16-08-10    16-04-23   14.05
3  s5  13-11-12    13-07-22   12.00
4  s5  17-11-14    17-06-20    1.54
5  s6  12-06-01    12-05-14    1.08
6  s7  18-11-19    18-10-16   12.49
7  s8  13-12-24    13-10-17   26.48
8  s8  16-01-20    15-06-29    3.72
```

Comment: You can use `as_index=False` like this: `df.groupby(['no','std_date'], as_index=False)['result_date'].max().merge(df, on=['no', 'std_date', 'result_date'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.idxmax()` which is less computationally expensive than a merge.

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['no', 'std_date'])['result_date'].idxmax()]
```